# i have an article driven from a db and it contains image tag, i need a regex to grab that image and put it into anchor tags

Tags: php

```
Some text before <img style="float: left;" src="../images/265218_imgthw.jpg" alt="" width="81" height="88"> some text after
```

Say i have something like that wrap inside some  text coming from db. I need it to be changed to:

```
Some text before <a href='../images/265218_imgthw.jpg'><img style="float: left;"     src="../images/265218_imgthw.jpg" alt="" width="81" height="88"></a> some text after
```

Any help please.
I tried breaking the code using the img tag with explode. It works fine but need to reduce the code using regEx. This is how i do it:

```
$string = "<img";
$explored = explode($string,$desc);
$desc = "";
foreach ($explored as $key => $value) {
static $counter = 0; 
if(strpos($explored[$key], '/>')){
$desc .= "<a href='".$path.$image[$counter]."' class='lightview'><img".$explored[$key];
$counter++;
} else $desc .= $explored[$key]."<a href='".$path.$image[$key]."' class='lightview'><img";
                        }


$string = "/>";
                        $explored = explode($string,$desc);
                        $desc = "";
                        foreach ($explored as $key => $value) {
                                if(strpos($explored[$key], '<img'))
                                {
                                    $desc .= $explored[$key]."/></a>";
                                }
                                else $desc .= $explored[$key];

                            }
```

Comment: I tried breaking the code using the <img tag with explode. It works fine but need to reduce the code using regEx.
I will add that to the code above.

Comment: It's 2013. Use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access) pretend that you have a variable named as $t

```
// '$t' is the element to be wrapped with anchor
$tempHtml = str_get_html('<a>' . $t->outertext . '</a>');
$link = $tempHtml->find('a', 0);
// '$src' is the url of the link
$link->href = $image['src'];
```